# Return data from a JQuery plugin with namespace

Tags: jquery

I want to create a JQuery plugin that uses a namespace. This is what I tried creating a simple function that returns html:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ns = function () {
        return {
            foo1: function(){
               var element = $(this);
               $(element).html('<b>hello</b>');
               return this;
            }
       }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Thus the namespace is supposed to be called ns.

It should fill this simple div:

```
<div class="sayHello"></div>
```

Calling it like this, seems not to work:

```
$(".sayHello").ns().foo1();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CVrFU/475/

Comment: there are numerous tutorials and boilerplates for jQuery plugins. Suggest reading them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way there must be a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) with element in it.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ns = function () {
        var self = this,
            element = $(this);

        return {
            foo1: function(){
               $(element).html('<b>hello</b>');
               return self;
            }
       }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

One more thin to save `this` in afret runs, there are few ways:

```
(function($) {
    var foo1 = function(){
       $(this).html('<b>hello</b>');
       return this;
    } 


    $.fn.ns = function () {
        var self = this;

        return {
            foo1: function () {
               return foo1.apply(self, arguments);
            }
       }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

In that way you don`t always recreate functions, and only run it in needed context.

http://jsfiddle.net/q303xwob/

But if you want save jQuery chaining, you should pass all your methods (in this example ns and foo1) in the fn object.

Comment: Thanks, but won't example two "pollute" the global namespace?

Comment: There is a upper closure with ready callback function - `(function($) {})` and all variables declared using `var`, so it all saved in local scope of this callback. Maybe you should read how `scope` in js works too. It would be helpfull, mozilla has a nice documentation and examples.